# RSpec failure ( undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass ) with has_many through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I can't make the spec to pass in the relationships controller. I have to change something about my object in the controller or the controller_spec.
Feel free to ask any doubt about my controller... thanks

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower

  # Follows a user.
  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end
end
```

user_spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  let(:user) { build(:user) }

  describe 'Validations' do
    it 'has a valid factory' do
      expect(user).to be_valid
    end

  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:other_user) { create(:user) }

  describe '#following?' do
    it "expect relationship between two users to be empty" do
      expect(user.active_relationships).to be_empty
    end
  end

  describe '#follow' do
    it "creates the active relationship between two users" do
      user.follow(other_user)
      expect(user.active_relationships.first.followed_id).to eq(other_user.id)
    end

    it "creates the passive relationship between two users" do
      user.follow(other_user)
      expect(other_user.passive_relationships.first.follower_id).to eq(user.id)
    end
  end

  describe '#unfollow' do
    it "destroys the active relationship between two users" do
      user.follow(other_user)
      expect{
        user.unfollow(other_user)
      }.to change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
end
```

relationship.rb

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Associations
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

#Validations
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    redirect_to user
  end

  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    redirect_to user
  end
end
```

relationships_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe RelationshipsController do
  let(:relationship) { create(:relationship) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  before do
    sign_in :user, create(:user)
  end

  describe '#create' do
    let!(:followed) { create(:user) }
    it "should require logged-in user to create relationship" do
      expect{
        post :create, followed_id: followed.id
      }.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  describe '#destroy' do
    let!(:relationship) { create(:relationship) }

    it "should require logged-in user to destroy relationship" do
      expect {
        delete :destroy, id: relationship.id
      }.to change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Relationship Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :relationship do
    follower_id 1
    followed_id 1
  end
end
```

Failures:

```
  1) RelationshipsController#destroy should require logged-in user to destroy relationship
     Failure/Error: active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

For `find` instead of `find_by`:

```
2) User#unfollow destroys the active relationship between two users
     Failure/Error: active_relationships.find(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "id"
       LINE 1: ...ips" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = $1 AND "id"."foll...
                                                                    ^
       : SELECT  "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = $1 AND "id"."followed_id" = 36 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The source of the issue is that for some reason `Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed` is returning nil, causing the subsequent line, `current_user.unfollow(user)` to give you the error you're seeing.

Are you sure that your `create(:relationship)` factory is properly setting the `followed` assocation in `Relationship`?

Also, looking at your controller spec, it's odd that you're defining `let!(:relationship) { create(:relationship) }` twice.

Why not declare one `let!(:relationship) { create(:relationship) }` (with `!`) at the start of your specs?

Finally, it might be more appropriate to use `find` instead of `find_by` in your `unfollow` method, to prevent calling `destroy` on nil, in the event that `find_by(followed_id: other_user.id)` doesn't exist.

Comment: the post has been updated with the factory and relationships.rb. Answering your first question : I think it is, as you can see in the updated post. Second : Thank you for the suggestion, I've corrected that :) . Third, using `find` instead of `find_by` rspec gives an error, as you can see above.